# Is there a way to keep Firefox from putting cached emails and passwords on my registration form?

Tags: html, firefox, forms

I have a site with registration & modify account forms. When a user navigates to one of these pages, Firefox is filling in certain areas of the form. It is filling in:

`<input type="text" name="nemail2" value="" />`

`<input type="password" name="npassword" value="" />`

Not sure why these names are original for this form, it can be the first time a user ever visits this form and it will fill in their username and password (not even in the correct boxes) from their cached passwords.

Note: the names of the actual login boxes are "emailaddr" and "password", also the `<label>` is different for these boxes that it is filling in. Not sure what I should do, it looks horrible when a user comes to edit their account information and half optional fields for changing their email/password are filled out with their current information.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use HTML5's  `autocomplete="off"`.

```
<input type="text" name="nemail2" value="" autocomplete="off" />

<input type="password" name="npassword" value="" autocomplete="off" />
```

You can also use it in the form element to turn off autocompletion for the entire form.

*Source:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en/how_to_turn_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: You may want to close the quotes properly on the type in the first input, but thanks for the answer. I, too, was puzzled by this.

Comment: I have also used the `autocomplete="off"` attribute with the`<form>` tag as well.  It sets removed autocomplete from all the enclosed form inputs.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams -  Excellent point, I think autocomplete in the form element may have better browser support. I don't know though if the OP wants it off in the entire form.

Comment: Thanks, BTW the quotes are closed in the form, I just typed that in here real fast and missed it, thanks

Comment: @Adam: I figured Mike may have wanted to preserve autocomplete on some fields, which is why I just added the comment.  It's nice to have most of the time, but I do *NOT* like to see forms that remember my CC number... yech.